# How to change the font and the size of a NavigationView menu item?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-navigationview

I'm trying to change the font and the size of the `first` element in my NavigationView programmatically . I thought I could do something like this:

```
nav.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_user).textSize = ...
nav.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_user).textFont = ...
```

but it seems that I can't or I don't know how. Any help?

Comment: have you tried changing navigationview theme programatically for different fontsize?

Comment: @TejasPandya Changing the theme of the NavigationView will lead to changing the size of the all elements in the menu. I need to change the first element only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SpannableString`:

```
val item: MenuItem = nav.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_user)
val spannableString = SpannableString(item.title.toString())
spannableString.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, spannableString.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
spannableString.setSpan(TypefaceSpan("font_name"), 0, spannableString.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
item.title = spannableString
```

the `RelativeSizeSpan` value `1.5f` is a relative and not absolute value for the text size, so adjust it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!